# Center TextView horizontally in parent as long there is space with xml layouting

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I want to center a title within a view as long it's possible and the space is not limited by surrounding buttons. Additionally, if the space is getting limited by the surrounding buttons, it should break into "maxLines".

To make it easy to understand, take a look at the following visualization:
[image]

Is this possible with xml layouting? Probably with TableLayout somehow?

Current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_back_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menuBtn"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/backBtn"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/shareBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/player_button_share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTV"
        android:tag="title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="short text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:maxLines="2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your xml

Comment: @PhanVanLinh done. For your info: it's not working

Comment: when you hide ImageButton, you use View.INVISIBLE or View.GONE

Comment: View.GONE to make space for title. View.INVISIBLE doesn't make sense here

Comment: so you use View.GONE for hide button right?

Comment: Yes, I use View.GONE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130447/discussion-between-phan-van-linh-and-arny).